# How to access variable in TypeScript after the file bundled?

Tags: javascript, typescript, browserify

I am new in TypeScript, I wrote some simple classes and methods but I don't know how to access to them!

I used gulp via `browserify`, `tsify` to bundle my `.ts` files to one file.

Imagine the main class name is `library` and here is that:

```
import {something} from "./someWhere";

class libraryClass{
  //Some code here too... 
}


var library = new libraryClass();

var testVar = "TypeScript";
```

now when I compile and bundle my files to one `.js` file, what I have inside the code works as expected (*such as console.log(s)*), but, how can I access my `libraryClass` class? How can I access the methods inside `libraryClass` class?!

Accessing the `libraryClass` does not work, nor `testVar`

example:

```
console.log(library)
console.log(testVar)
```

Both returns

> Uncaught ReferenceError: library is not defined Uncaught
>
> ReferenceError: testVar is not defined

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015.promise", "es5"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html ?

Comment: @zerkms the problem did not solve, can you help please

Comment: You don't export anything in your code. "the problem did not solve" --- what did you do to solve it?

Comment: @zerkms I read some pages on the web and I also used the same configs that the typeScript website said, but still does not work. I just know I should use system module, but still not working and just I get another error on browser which says *System is not defined*

Comment: @TypeScriptLearner I think what you're looking for is `--standalone` parameter https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#standalone

Comment: @martin Thank you, I will check this out now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call TypeScript functions out of the .ts files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234985/how-to-call-typescript-functions-out-of-the-ts-files)