# Use TypeScript class in another JavaScript file after browserify bundling (Gulp build)

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, browserify

I read the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234985/how-to-call-typescript-functions-out-of-the-ts-files), because my TypeScript class is `undefined` in antoher javascript file. In the other question M98 said to add a standalone to browserify to use it globaly.

I am new to browserify and typescript also gulp.

TypeScript class:

```
export class Test {
  static log = function(what: string) : void {
    console.log(what);
  }
} 
//export { Test }
```

Browserify / Gulp Task:

```
gulp.task('compile-ts', ['clean-ts'], function () {
    var tsFiles = glob.sync(config.js.tsSource);

    return browserify({
        standalone: "tsLib",
        basedir: ".",            
        debug: true,             
        entries: tsFiles
    })
        .external(["jquery"])   
        .plugin(tsify)          
        .bundle()               
        .pipe(source("modules.js")) 
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.js.tsDest)); 
});
```

My typescript class is undefined in my test javascript file, because of that I created another typescript file and add the following:

```
import {Test} from "./test-file";

export function log(log:string) {
    Test.log(log);
}
```

I want to use my TypeScript class in a JavaScript file as the following example:

```
function onLoad() {
  tsLib.log("test"); // I dont want that
  Test.log("test");  // I would like to use this, but it's undefined
}
```

`tsLib.log` is a workaround to use my Test class, but I just want to call log as `Test.log("whatever");`.
Is this possible?
Can anyone give me hint?

Edit:
If I use the TypeScript file without browserify and just use the TypeScript compiler it seems to be working, but I want to understand this issue.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm really not familiar with gulp, but when you define a task, the others that are specified in the array must be executed first, right? Is the task _['clean-ts']_ supposed to run _**before**_  'compile-ts' ?

Comment: yes clean-ts runs before compile-ts.

Comment: For everyone whos interested in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472464/how-to-provide-global-typescript-classes-via-webpack-bundle-in-js